# Receiving an specific Erc721 token and minting a new erc721

Tags: dapps, erc-721, nft

Is there a way to make a mint function that only mint a token if it receives a specific token e.g. BAYC

```
require(if the token is BAYC);
unit sameTokenId = recivedBAYC.tokenId;
transfer to this contract;
//mint
_safeMint(msg.sender, sameTokenId);
```

also I don't know where the erc721reciver.sol is needed in both contracts or not.

tnx u in advance;

Comment: How would you mint the first token? the BAYC one? would you have 2 functions minting tokens? what ideas have you explored?

Comment: imagine this I want make a contract that people transfer their board ape(BAYC is already on the chain and I'm not the creator) to the contract and the contract create Dead Board ape(a new nft that only mint when it receives a board ape) and give it to the sender.